# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting the above error When I accessing the `http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts/show` url its giving me the error

```
Couldn't find Post with id=show
Extracted source (around line #5) 

def show
@post = Post.find(params[:id])--here is line number 5
end
def create
@post = Post.new(post_params)

activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:198:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'
```

same problem when I am accessing the url `http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts/index...`

```
my controller file is
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
end
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
  def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  @post.save
  redirect_to @post
  # or this command also works redirect_to action: :show, id: @post.id
end

def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end

end

my routes.rb file is
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  root to: "posts#index"
end
```

index.html.rb file is

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>
 <h3><%= link_to 'New post', new_post_path %></h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= post.title %></td>
      <td><%= post.text %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<h1>Hello,Rails</h1>
<%=link_to "My Blog",controller: "posts"%>
```

show.html.rb file is

this is show file for listing information from database,this file is giving problem when accessing from url directly this is show file for listing information from database,this file is giving problem when accessing from url directly this is show file for listing information from database,this file is giving problem when accessing from url directly this is show file for listing information from database,this file is giving problem when accessing from url directly this is show file for listing information from database,this file is giving problem when accessing from url directly

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title  %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @post.text %>
</p>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

this is show file for listing information from database,this file is giving problem when accessing from url directly this is show file for listing information from database,this file is giving problem when accessing from url directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply an id. A record isn't found because you are supplying "show" as the id. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#code-user_show_action

example: visit posts/1 instead of posts/show

Comment: And for the index simply /posts. Or simply the root only, since it is defined in the routes.rb as root.

Comment: if I want to use posts/show instead of posts/1 how can I get the result?

Comment: What are you trying to see with posts/show? You can map the routes /show to go wherever you want. As @rails4guides.com stated, if you wanted to show all the posts, just visit "localhost:3000/posts" for the index.

Basic routing info off the rails tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-rails_routes

More in-depth routing info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html